# Combining 2 event tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 events tracking tables:

First table:

| ID | Event_Name | Event_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | xxxxxxxxxx | 2019-12-01 |

Second table:

| ID | Event_Name | Event_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | yyyyyyyyyy | 2019-12-02 |

The tables are of 2 different event names,first table has event name 'xxxxxxxxxx' and 2nd has 'yyyyyyyyyy'. I would like to combine these 2, such that the resulting table is as below:

| ID | Event_Name | Event_Start_Date | Event_End_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | xxxxxxxxxx | 2019-12-01 | 2019-12-02 |
| 1111 | yyyyyyyyyy | 2019-12-02 | 2019-12-05 |

meaning the Event_Date of 'xxxxxxxx' is the Event_Start_Date of the'xxxxxxxx' then the Event_End_Date of event 'xxxxxxxxx' is the Event_Date of 'yyyyyyyy' and so on for the rest of the events. All the event names are known and finite.

Comment: [`UNION ALL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) (and `LAG`/`LEAD`)? Where does the date `2019-12-05` come from? It isn't in your data.

Comment: @Larnu, UNION_ALL creates a table with the same 3 columns not the 4 columns ( 2 date columns). 2019-12-05 would be the start date of the event in the 3rd row.

Comment: Which is why I mention `LAG`/`LEAD` as well after I edited the comment; I admit initially only stated `UNION ALL`, but your expected results [weren't in the question at the time](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74601190/5) I opened it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use `UNION ALL` here, and then `LEAD` to get the start date of the next event. As you don't explain where the date `2019-12-05` comes from, I just put it in as the value for `LEAD` to return if there isn't another row:

```sql
WITH Events AS(
    --I assume that the data types in the 2 tables are identical
    --If not CAST/CONVERT appropriately
    SELECT ID,
           Event_Name,
           Event_Date
    FROM dbo.FirstTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID,
           Event_Name,
           Event_Date
    FROM dbo.SecondTable)
SELECT ID,
       Event_Name,
       Event_Date AS Event_Start_Date,
       LEAD(Event_Date,1,'20191205') OVER (ORDER BY EventDate ASC) AS Event_End_Date
FROM Events;
```